# Footer is not moving down as per increase in the height of content

Tags: asp.net, css

I am trying to push the footer in to down when the content page height increase.but I am not able to do that. footer is always stick with side bar.because of this my content page overflow over the footer .

My css code is below:

```
#header 
{ 
  height: 150px; 
  background-color: #375BB0; 
} 

#nav 
{ 
    **strong text**height: 100%; 
   width: 231px; 
   float: left; 
} 

  #nav2 
{ 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 250px; 
    float: right; 
 }
 #content 
 { 
   height: 100%; 
   bottom: 0;

    } 

 #footer 
 { 
    clear: both; 
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC; 
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

My markup code:

```
 <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

          <div id="header">
          </div>
           <div id="nav">
              <table class="style1" style="width: 100%; position: static ;" >
              </table>
        </div>
        <div id="nav2">
            <table style="border: 1px solid #000066; width: 100%; position: static;background-color:#9DAFD8;" >
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        </div>
        <div id="footer" style="clear: both; height:500px;" >
            Copy rihgt @ xyzoman.com
        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I changed 2 things. First, you were making the height of elements at 100% to an element that was 100% to the page, so they would never line up unless the content was bigger than the page, and 2, I made the content `display: inline block;` so that your menus would be on either side and not just on teh side and then to wrap around the content, but you can change this back if you wanted.. But your main main main issue was the height 100% in the nav css tags!

Everything else stayed the same.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#header 
{ 
  height: 150px; 
  background-color: #375BB0; 
} 

#nav 
{ 
   width: 231px; 
   float: left; 
} 

  #nav2 
{ 
    width: 250px; 
    float: right;
 }
 #content 
 {
 display:inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 bottomL 0;
 }
#footer {
    display:block;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC; 
    color: #333333;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

          <div id="header">
          </div>
           <div id="nav">
              <table class="style1" style="width: 100%; position: static ;" >
              <tr><td>Table</tr>
              </table>
        </div>
        <div id="nav2">
            <table style="border: 1px solid #000066; width: 100%; position: static;background-color:#9DAFD8;" >
              <tr><td>Table</tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
              <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
              </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

       </div>
         <div id="footer" style="clear: both; height:500px;" >
            Copy rihgt @ xyzoman.com
        </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code.But still is not working footer is going up.Thank your  for your response

Comment: Im sorry, but I tried this in 3 browsers and it works fine, using the exact code I wrote above word for word, it works. If it is not working, then nothing in the above is causing it. I would look at things like what else you have inbetween the body like other divs you may have left out from this post. I would also make sure that you have the proper doctype at the top.

Comment: Where do you want your footer?